# replace word of first part string in python

Tags: python

In Python, I would like to replace the "be" into "nl" in the following string:

```
http://test.nl/be/nl/product/abc-dadf-adsfsw-12234/
```

BUT!! I want it to check the part BEFORE /product/, because if the string after /product/ contains a "be" it has to remain the same.

Examples:

http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/ (part BEFORE /product/ contains no be, so has to remain the same)

http://test.nl/be/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/ (part BEFORE /product/ contains be, so it has to be replaced with nl, so it becomes http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/)

http://test.be/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/ (part BEFORE /product/ contains be, so it has to be replaced with nl, so it becomes http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/)

Comment: Could you give an example of when "be" has to remain the same?

Comment: To clarify: What would your url be *after* replacement?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? Are the strings you're doing the replacement in always in this exact format of `"http://test.nl/be/nl/product/.*"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookahead for this.

```
url = '''http://test.nl/be/nl/product/abc-dadf-adsfsw-12234/'''
url = re.sub("/be/(?=.*/product/)", "/nl/", url)
# or using word boundary around `be` to handle .be/ .be. etc
# url = re.sub("\bbe\b(?=.*/product/)", "nl", url)
print url
```

This positive lookahead `(?=.*/product/)` is checking that there is `/product/` exists after the `/be/` in front.

But remember, this regex is true for any `/be/` which are before `/product/`. In general I am talking about multiple occurrence.

Comment: Your answer works and with least code, thanks!:) Is there a possibility to double check or it contains /product/ OR /forum/ ?

Comment: @ErikVandeVen everything. Try this `(?=.*/(?:product|forum|another|more|any)/)`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of doing that is splitting the string with a regular expression. Here is some code that should give you the desired output.

```
import re #python's regular expression module
string = 'http://test.nl/be/nl/product/abc-dadf-adsfsw-12234/'

search = re.match('(.*)(product.*)', string)
first_part = search.group(1)
next_part = search.group(2)

first_part = first_part.replace('be', 'nl')

new_string = first_part + next_part
print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option without regexp (and no imports):

```
elements = raw_input('URL?\n').split('/')

for i in range(0, elements.index('product')):
    elements[i] = elements[i].replace('be', 'nl')

print '/'.join(elements)
```

Tests:

```
http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/
  -> http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/

http://test.nl/be/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/
  -> http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/

http://test.be/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/
  -> http://test.nl/nl/nl/product/abc-dadf-be-adsfsw-12234/
```